# Transitions taking place in NFA

Tags: theory

While studying about NFA and DFA in Compiler Design I couldn't get how they converted an regular expression to NFA as shown in [NFA](http://1drv.ms/1xnAN5e).I would like to know why there is an epsilon transition between `(8 -> 10)` and `(9 -> 10)`.

Because I think even if we don't write states 9 and 10 the NFA would be unaffected.  Can anyone tell me whether this is correct to do like that?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "correct?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey:That means I would like to know whether even if you remove states 9 and 10 whether this(change) would affect the NFA?

Comment: FYI that NFA matches the regular expression `(ab|c)*` the DFA for that is pretty simple with only 2 states (plus a  garbage state): a starting/accepting state with a `c`-loopback and a transition `a`to another state which has a transition `b` back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without states 9 and 10, we need a new start and accept state.  Lets assume that these are states 7 for start (because there is an ε transition from 9 to 7) and 8 for accept (because there is an ε from 8 to 10).

However, this doesn't match the empty string anymore.

The diagram shown is the regular expression `/^(ab|c)*$/`.  Without states 9 or 10 and the transition, the regular expression representing this NFA would be `/^(ab|c)+$/` which is different.

Comment: :Thanks for your answer.I understood the answer but whether we could make it into `/^(ab|c)*$/` by adding a transition `(7 -> 8)`?

Comment: If you added an ε transition from 7->8, correct, states 9 and 10 wouldn't be necessary. Though note that you're now dealing more with conventions of writing NFAs. The depicted one is a bit more explicit about start and end states - probably the author's preference. DFAs have a canonical way to represent them, but NFA-ε are not so much because there are multiple ways to write the same NFA-ε. I personally am not overfly fond of this style of depiction - there are a lot of transitions that seem excessive; though thats the thing with instruction that they're trying to drill a specific point home.

Comment: @justin I'd also suggest that you might want to look over at [ComputerScience.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com).  Programmers.SE tends to be more practical than theoretical (writing funny characters like ε makes us worry someone is going to stick them in an identifier at times).  CS.SE is more focused on the theoretical than we are here and aren't afraid at throwing around greek characters and mathjax in the answers. You might want to look at the [finite-automata](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata) tag there if you are after more in-depth answers.

Comment: ... over here, you get crazy perl programmers who occasionally remember things they studied back in college.

Comment: @MichealT:yeah know I got it.Could you also answer this post:http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/262873/significance-of-nfa-in-compiler-design/262887?noredirect=1#comment534287_262887

Comment: @justin I'll look at it again (later), though as I write this, it's a bit late for me and my writing skills decline rapidly after a hot cider + brandy on a cold night.

Comment: :Oh that's no problem.I would keep looking for your anwser.

Comment: Another reason for this way of writing the NFA is that it allows for a completely mechanical transformation from a regex to an NFA that could even be performed by a machine with a minimum of rules.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:Thanks for your comment.Could you say whether DFA can be used for mechanical transformation?

Comment: @justin: DFA's and NFA's are usually used for recognizing stuff and they are only sideways involved with taking actions after something has been recognized. But you can certainly construct a DFA to recognize the syntax of a regular expression.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:Thanks.Is NFA useful for Backtracking?I have got this from the answer posted here:http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/262873/significance-of-nfa-in-compiler-design/262887?noredirect=1#comment534287_262887.But really couldn't understand what 'backtracking' means in context of NFA.

Comment: @justin: If you implement an NFA (without transforming it to a DFA), you can only try a single transition at a time. If a state has ε transitions, it can be that taking that transition is the wrong choice and you need to undo that. That is what is meant by backtracking here.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:So does that mean 'NFA' is an list of available choices and 'DFA' is the choice we made?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18833/discussion-between-bart-van-ingen-schenau-and-justin).

Comment: @MichaelT: Could you now look at this post:https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/262873/significance-of-nfa-in-compiler-design

Comment: @MichaelT:Should I improve the question posted on the link:https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/262873/significance-of-nfa-in-compiler-design?